# Understanding the $\tau$ Branching Fractions from PDG

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

[On PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/), page 6 ff., we can find the branching ratios for the different $\tau$ decay channels.

My problem is that taken together, these do not sum to unity, but are greater than $1$, which I find really confusing.

As an example:

[image]

[image]

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Sure, but I want it to make easier for people to relate to where it says on PDG..

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they do not add up to unity when they are inclusive states, there will be overlaps where the same channels will fulfill the "larger or equal " criteria.

The probability will sum up to one of all decays are identified with specific number and type of particle . These are the ratios after before   $Γ_{11}$ and after $Γ_{18}$, those  without "less than or equal" signs  in your link. Their summation will always be less than 1.

Copying from comment by  Martino  :

> They actually explain what [they do here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-tau-branching-fractions.pdf), but it's a little bit technical.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid it's rather hard for me to follow. What do you mean by "inclusive states"?

Comment: But I still don't agree with your main statement: Let's consider $\mu^{-}\bar{\nu}_{\mu}\nu_{\tau}$ ($17.39 \%$, $\Gamma_3$),  $e^{-}\bar{\nu}_{e}\nu_{\tau}$ ($17.82 \%$, $\Gamma_4$), $\pi^{-}\pi^{0}\nu_{\tau}$ ($25.49 \%$, $\Gamma_{14}$), etc. There are enough final-states that are definite (so do not contain $\geq$) and these branching ratios still don't sum to $1$.. Do you agree so far?

Comment: inclusive states means that they do not have a fixed number of the other particles. When the particles are identified and fixed , the sum cannot be larger than one. It will  probably always be smaller, because not all possible channels have been measured.

Comment: watch the $10^{-3}$  in some of the identifiable channels

Comment: They actually explain what they do here: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-tau-branching-fractions.pdf , but it's a little bit technical. In short, sum of all exclusive modes (i.e. fully defined final states) is 1.

Comment: As a side comment, if you go to less-studied particles, like the Lambda_b baryon for example, you will see that the sum of all branching fractions is far below 100%. This is simply because there are hundreds allowed decay modes, and majority of them has not been measured yet.

Comment: Thanks @Martino for the link.